# In Python, how do I iterate over a dictionary in sorted key order?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

There's an existing function that ends in the following, where `d` is a dictionary:

```
return d.iteritems()
```

that returns an unsorted iterator for a given dictionary. I would like to return an iterator that goes through the items sorted *by key*. How do I do that?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

Haven't tested this very extensively, but works in Python 2.5.2.

```
>>> d = {"x":2, "h":15, "a":2222}
>>> it = iter(sorted(d.iteritems()))
>>> it.next()
('a', 2222)
>>> it.next()
('h', 15)
>>> it.next()
('x', 2)
>>>
```

If you are used to doing `for key, value in d.iteritems(): ...` instead of iterators, this will still work with the solution above

```
>>> d = {"x":2, "h":15, "a":2222}
>>> for key, value in sorted(d.iteritems()):
>>>     print(key, value)
('a', 2222)
('h', 15)
('x', 2)
>>>
```

With Python 3.x, use `d.items()` instead of `d.iteritems()` to return an iterator.

Comment: use `.items()` instead of `iteritems()`: as @Claudiu said, iteritems does not work for Python 3.x, but `items()` is available from Python 2.6.

Comment: This is not obvious. In fact, `items()` creates a list and therefore uses memory, whereas `iteritems()` essentially does not use memory. What to use mostly depend on the size of the dictionary. Furthermore, the automatic Python 2 to Python 3 conversion tool (`2to3`) automatically takes care of the conversion from `iteritems()` to `items()`, so there is no need to worry about this.

Comment: Is it possible to optimize it in case both getitem and sorted iteration are very frequently needed?

Comment: @HowerHell use a `collections.OrderedDict` then you sort once & get items in sorted order always.

Comment: But @EOL, even if `iteritems()` does not use memory, everything must be pulled into memory for `sorted()`, so there is no difference between the use of `items()` and `iteritems()` here memory-wise.

Comment: @Richard: While it is true that all the elements must be pulled into memory, they are *stored* twice with `items()` (in the list returned by `items()`, and in the sorted list) and only once with `iteritems()` (in the sorted list only).

Answer (score 86):

Use the [`sorted()`](http://pydoc.org/2.5.1/__builtin__.html#-sorted) function:

```
return sorted(dict.iteritems())
```

If you want an actual iterator over the sorted results, since `sorted()` returns a list, use:

```
return iter(sorted(dict.iteritems()))
```

Comment: That fails for me: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'

Comment: That's probably because you use "dict" as the variable name. "dict" is actually the type name of dictionaries. Just use another name like "mydict" here and voila.

Comment: Still not working. Are you positive sorted() returns another iterator, as opposed to a regular list?

Comment: when and where does this exception occur? you can iterate over a list without a problem

Comment: it could fail if you were calling the .next() method on the list, which would work on the iterator

Comment: well, i somehow took that problem as trivial ;)

Comment: Agreed, hop. I don't think I ever call .next() directly except when skipping lines in files. Our iter(sorted(dict.iteritems())) solution ends up making a copy of the whole dict in memory at the "sorted(" stage anyway, so the primary iterator benefit seems lost :)

Comment: It needs to plug into an existing API that's expecting an iterator.

Answer (score 43):

A dict's keys are stored in a hashtable so that is their 'natural order', i.e. psuedo-random. Any other ordering is a concept of the consumer of the dict.

sorted() always returns a list, not a dict. If you pass it a dict.items() (which produces a list of tuples), it will return a list of tuples [(k1,v1), (k2,v2), ...] which can be used in a loop in a way very much like a dict, but *it is not in anyway a dict*!

```
foo = {
    'a':    1,
    'b':    2,
    'c':    3,
    }

print foo
>>> {'a': 1, 'c': 3, 'b': 2}

print foo.items()
>>> [('a', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2)]

print sorted(foo.items())
>>> [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

The following feels like a dict in a loop, but it's not, it's a list of tuples being unpacked into k,v:

```
for k,v in sorted(foo.items()):
    print k, v
```

Roughly equivalent to:

```
for k in sorted(foo.keys()):
    print k, foo[k]
```

Comment: Okay, but I don't want a Dict or a List, I want an Iterator. How do i coerce it into being an Iterator?

Comment: `sorted(foo.keys())` is better as the equivalent `sorted(foo)`, since dictionaries return their keys when iterated over (with the advantage of not being forced to create the `foo.keys()` intermediate list, maybe—depending on how `sorted()` is implemented for iterables).

Comment: Wonder which is better for speed and/or memory `k in sorted(foo.keys()):` which pulls the keys or `for k,v in sorted(foo.items()):` which returns a copy of the dictionary’s list pairs I would guess `sorted(foo.keys())`

Comment: @CrandellWS: The best way to answer the time question is with the Python [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module.

Comment: @peter Rowell thank you did not even know about `timeit` I will give it a go.

Comment: @PeterRowell I did run several tests had to back it down to 250k and found no clear winner, though was able to run it at a million and from what I can see I will use `k in sorted(foo.keys()):` see ->https://github.com/CrandellWS/Udacity-Nanodegree/commit/06aa1ebd95664c1f6f1a75e2ef87f3d9346c207b

Comment: @CrandellWS: Glad that was useful for you. Other things to consider before getting too far gone into Optimization Land include: How often is this routine called? If the input changes infrequently can you cache the result? Etc. Actual testing and timing are the only way to answer that eternal question: "It's 11pm. Do you know where *your* program is spending its time?"

Comment: @PeterRowell When I've been using dicts in python 3, however, and I call `for k,v in d.items()`, it's always returned the keys in the order I inserted them.  Is this something I can count on?

Comment: @frank -- Short Answer: No. A dict is an array with the actual key being a *hash* of the value of the supplied key. Although some implementations may be fairly predictable, and some may even make this contract, I count on *nothing* when it comes to hash ordering. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6) for more on 3.6+ behavior. In particular note the first answer.

Answer (score 35):

Greg's answer is right. Note that in Python 3.0 you'll have to do

```
sorted(dict.items())
```

as `iteritems` will be gone.

Comment: That fails for me: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'list'

Comment: "Dont make use of cars because in the future we will have hoverboards"

Answer (score 7):

You can now use `OrderedDict` in Python 2.7 as well:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> d = OrderedDict([('first', 1),
...                  ('second', 2),
...                  ('third', 3)])
>>> d.items()
[('first', 1), ('second', 2), ('third', 3)]
```

Here you have the [what's new](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html) page for 2.7 version and the [OrderedDict API](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: That will return key,values in the order they are inserted - not in a sorted order (i.e. alphabetic).

Answer (score 6):

In general, one may sort a dict like so:

```
for k in sorted(d):
    print k, d[k]
```

For the specific case in the question, having a "drop in replacement" for d.iteritems(), add a function like:

```
def sortdict(d, **opts):
    # **opts so any currently supported sorted() options can be passed
    for k in sorted(d, **opts):
        yield k, d[k]
```

and so the ending line changes from

```
return dict.iteritems()
```

to

```
return sortdict(dict)
```

or

```
return sortdict(dict, reverse = True)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> import heapq
>>> d = {"c": 2, "b": 9, "a": 4, "d": 8}
>>> def iter_sorted(d):
        keys = list(d)
        heapq.heapify(keys) # Transforms to heap in O(N) time
        while keys:
            k = heapq.heappop(keys) # takes O(log n) time
            yield (k, d[k])


>>> i = iter_sorted(d)
>>> for x in i:
        print x


('a', 4)
('b', 9)
('c', 2)
('d', 8)
```

This method still has an O(N log N) sort, however, after a short linear heapify, it yields the items in sorted order as it goes, making it theoretically more efficient when you do not always need the whole list.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to sort by the order that items were inserted instead of of the order of the keys, you should have a look to Python's [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict). (Python 3 only)

Answer (score 3):

sorted returns a list, hence your error when you try to iterate over it,
but because you can't order a dict you will have to deal with a list.

I have no idea what the larger context of your code is, but you could try adding an
iterator to the resulting list. 
like this maybe?:

```
return iter(sorted(dict.iteritems()))
```

of course you will be getting back tuples now because sorted turned your dict into a list of tuples

ex:
 say your dict was:
 `{'a':1,'c':3,'b':2}`
sorted turns it into a list:

```
[('a',1),('b',2),('c',3)]
```

so when you actually iterate over the list you get back (in this example) a tuple
composed of a string and an integer, but at least you will be able to iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using CPython 2.x and have a large dictionary mydict, then using sorted(mydict) is going to be slow because sorted builds a sorted list of the keys of mydict.

In that case you might want to look at my ordereddict package which includes a C implementation of `sorteddict` in C. Especially if you have to go over the sorted list of keys multiple times at different stages (ie. number of elements) of the dictionaries lifetime.

http://anthon.home.xs4all.nl/Python/ordereddict/