# Sorting a python dictionary by name?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a python dictionary that I want to sort according to name:

```
location_map_india = {
  101: {'name': 'Andaman & Nicobar Islands', 'lat': 11.96, 'long': 92.69, 'radius': 294200},  
  108: {'name': 'Andhra Pradesh', 'lat': 17.04, 'long': 80.09, 'radius': 294200},
...
}
```

It doesn't come out the way I expect it. I tried:

```
location_map_india = sorted(location_map_india.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x.name)
```

The above didn't work. What should I do?

**Update**

The following was allowed and behaved as expected. Thanks for all the help.
Code:

```
location_map_india = sorted(location_map_india.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]["name"])
```

Template:

```
{% for key,value in location_map_india %}<option value="{{key}}" >{{value.name}}</option>{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an order and thus can't be sorted. What is your goal here?

Comment: Depending on your Python Version you could use an OrderedDict instead of a standard dictionary.  It's in the collections module.  Otherwise, explain your intent for better suggestions on approach.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/364519/346587

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I had a data structure and I would like to order it by name in that natural order. It seems it's not that simple.

Comment: use `.items()` instead if  `.iteritems()` to assure compatibility with Python 3.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are close. Try:

```
location_map_india = sorted(location_map_india.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1]["name"])
```

but the result would be a list not a dict. dict is orderless.

Comment: I understand. But I want the key/value pairs and in order. What should I do?

Comment: What I wrote will give you that. It will be list of (key,value) tuples sorted according to "name".

Comment: Thanks. I could make it loop but I couldn't make it print the info: `{% for a in location_map_india %}<option value="{{ a.key }}" >{{ a.value }}</option>{% endfor %}`

Comment: I have no idea what language that is. But if you want to access elements after the sorting I gave, use a[0] for key and a[1] for value.

Comment: Ok. The language is django templates where I pass the variable to the template and then iterate over it. In this case iterating becomes rather difficult since i don't know how to access the elements in django templates.

Comment: @Niklas R: django part beats me. I'm not familiar with it. Just looked the doc for syntax and might i suggest a.0 or a.1 or a.1.name?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using python 2.7 or superior, take a look at [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). Using it may solve your problem.

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['name']))
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try

```
location_map_india = sorted(location_map_india.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['name'])
```

Comment: Thanks but how to access it from template tag? I've tried `{% for a in location_map_india %}<option value="{{ a.key }}" >{{ a.value }}</option>{% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a dictionary that must have order in any way, you are not using the correct data structure.

Try list or tuples instead.