# How to order my dictionary in python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Python, how to I iterate over a dictionary in sorted order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364519/in-python-how-to-i-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-sorted-order)

I need help in dictionaries. I have two dictionaries, and I want to add the values of identical keys in those two dictionaries. I need to make a list of summing the values that has the same key. I did the list but those values that their keys are the only ones in the two dictionaries are added after finishing all calculations. What I mean is:

```
dectionary1= {8: 2, 0: 6, 2: 5, 3: 34}  
dectionary2= {8: 6, 1: 2, 3: 2}
```

My list must be:

```
summing= [6, 2, 5, 36, 8]
```

since it will take 0 and check whether there is 0 in dectionary 2, and then it will TAKE 1 (NOT 2) and check whether it's found in dectionary 1 in order to order the list.

I got this so far:

```
summing=[8, 6, 5, 36, 2]
```

Here it initially takes key (8) not (0)!! I want it to be in order.

To see my code, that what I got so far:

```
dic1= {8: 2, 0: 6, 2: 5, 3: 34}  
dic2= {8: 6, 1: 2, 3: 2}
p=[]
for x in dic1:
    if x in dic2:
        g=dic1[x]+dic2[x]
        p=p+[g]
    else:
        p=p+[dic1[x]]
for m in dic2:
    if m in dic1:
        p=p
    else:
        p=p+[dic2[m]]
```

I think if I can make the dictionaries ascendingly ordered, it will be much easier, but how?

My python is Wing IDE 3.2

Thank you

Comment: `common_keys = set(dic1.keys()) & set(dic2.keys())`. And dict elements are not sorted so you there is no such thing as "in order" for your case.

Answer (score 8):

You have two options here, one is to use [`collections.OrderedDict()`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), but I think the easier option is simply to do it this way:

```
[dic1.get(x, 0)+dic2.get(x, 0)for x in sorted(dic1.keys() | dic2.keys())]
```

We first make a set of any keys [in either of the dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.union), [sort this into the right order](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#sorted), and then [loop over it with a list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY), adding the two values [(or 0 if the value doesn't already exist)](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
>>> dic1= {8: 2, 0: 6, 2: 5, 3: 34}  
>>> dic2= {8: 6, 1: 2, 3: 2}
>>> [dic1.get(x, 0)+dic2.get(x, 0)for x in sorted(dic1.keys() | dic2.keys())]
[6, 2, 5, 36, 8]
```

Note that this only works in 3.x, where [`dict.keys()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a [set-like dictionary view](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). If you want to do this in python 2.7.x, use [`dict.viewkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewkeys) instead, earlier than that, `set(dict.iterkeys())` would be optimal.

Comment: Please double check the syntax. Raise `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'list' and 'list'` (even with space between `)` and `for`) in Python 2.7.x

Comment: Must be `[dic1.get(x, 0)+dic2.get(x, 0) for x in sorted(set(dic1.keys()) | set(dic2.keys()))]`

Comment: in python3, `[dic1.get(x, 0)+dic2.get(x, 0)for x in sorted(dic1.keys() | dic2.keys())]`should work, too (no need for the `set()` )

Comment: @ch3ka I know, in Python 3.x, keys() returns a `view` object, but returns a `list` in Python 2.x. I indicated that this will fail in 2.7.x (for clarity).

Comment: @PraveenGollakota As you posted that I added in my note at the end. The best option in 2.x is to use `viewkeys()`.

Comment: @ch3ka Indeed, I edited it to reflect that.

Comment: @Lattyware To nitpick, `viewkeys()` works only in `2.7.x`, not `2.x` but I understand the sentiment :). Thanks for the update!