# Sorting an OrderedDict both ascendingly and descendingly

Tags: python, sorting, ordereddict

**Define:**

```
diction = {"Book":(1, 2), "Armchair":(2, 2), "Lamp":(1, 3)}
```

If one wants to sort this dictionary by item["key"][1] descendingly and by "keys" ascendingly, what will be the appropriate way?

**Desired output:**

```
diction = {"Lamp":(1, 3), "Armchair":(2, 2), "Book":(1, 2)}
```

**After receiving the correct answer by Sinan** Note that I did not ask about sorting either ascendingly or descendingly, that you sent me the relevant links!  I asked about doing both at the same time which is not solved by the trick of minus given by Sinan.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I sort this dictionary with alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939732/how-can-i-sort-this-dictionary-with-alphabetically)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001509/how-can-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: None of them are asking my question, note that I asked about sorting both ascendingly and descendingly. The correct link and answer are given by @Sinan below.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17109098/5411878).

```
from collections import OrderedDict
diction = {"Book":(1, 2), "Armchair":(2, 2), "Lamp":(1, 3)}
diction_list = list(diction.items())
diction = OrderedDict(sorted(diction_list, key=lambda x: (-x[1][1], x[0])))
print(diction)

OrderedDict([('Lamp', (1, 3)), ('Armchair', (2, 2)), ('Book', (1, 2))])
```

Here is where  the magic is happening:

```
sorted(diction_list, key=lambda x: (-x[1][1], x[0]))
```

`sorted` sorts stuff for you. It is very good at it. If you use the `key` parameter with sort, you can give it a function to be used on each item to be sorted.
In this case, we are giving at a `lambda` that returns the negative value from the tuples `-x[1][1]` (this is the second value in the tuple) and the key `x[0]`. The negative sign makes it sort in reverse. Of course, this would not work with non-numeric values.

The `OrderedDict` thing is not strictly necessary. Python keeps dict in order after version 3.6 I think (or was it 3.7?). OrderedDicts are always kept in the same order, so it is there that so our dict stays ordered independent of the Python version.

For a better way of doing this see the [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto) in Python Documentation.

Comment: Great, Thanks so much!