# Properly looping over a dictionary / using dictionaries as databases

Tags: python, dictionary

This looks like a CS 101 style homework but it actually isn't. I am trying to learn more python so I took up this personal project to write a small app that keeps my grade-book for me.

I have a class `semester` which holds a dictionary of `section` objects.
A section is a class that I am teaching in which ever semester object I am manipulating (I didn't want to call them classes for obvious reasons). I originally had sections as a list not a dictionary, and when I wanted to add a roster of `students` to that `semester` I could do this.

```
for sec in working_semester.sections:
    sec.addRosterFromFile(filename)
```

Now I have changed the `sections` member of `semester` to a dictionary so I can look up a specific one to work with, but I am having trouble when I want to loop over all of them to do something like when I first set up a new semester I want to add all the sections, then loop over them and add students to each. If I try the same code to loop over the dictionary it gives me the key, but I was hoping to get the value.

I have also tried to iterate over a dictionary like this, which I got out of an [older stack over flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364519/in-python-how-to-i-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-sorted-order)

```
for sec in iter(sorted(working_semester.sections.iteritems())):
    sec.addRosterFromFile(filename)
```

But `iter(sorted ...` returns a tuple (key, value) not the item so the line in side the loop gives me an error that tuple does not have a function called addStudent.

Currently I have this fix in place where I loop through the keys and then use the key to access the value like this:

```
for key in working_semester.sections:
    working_semester.sections[key].addRosterFromFile(filename)
```

There has to be a way to loop over dictionary values, or is this not desirable? My understanding of dictionaries is that they are like lists but rather than grabbing an element by its position it has a specific key, which makes it easier to grab the one you want no matter what order they are in. Am I missing how dictionaries should be used?

Comment: If you only want the *values* from the dictionary, use `itervalues` not `iteritems`. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `iteritems` is a good approach, you just need to unpack the key and value:

```
for key, value in iter(sorted(working_semester.sections.iteritems())):
    value.addRosterFromFile(filename)
```

If you really only need the value, you could use the aptly named `itervalues`:

```
for sec in sorted(working_semester.sections.itervalues()):
    sec.addRosterFromFile(filename)
```

(It's not clear from your example whether you really need `sorted` there.  If you don't need to iterate over the sections in sorted order just leave `sorted` out.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wanted sorted in there so that I could list the students in alphabetical order. The keys are their last names.  Two good pieces of info here. 1. I never realize that the for x,y in something() syntax meant something returns a tuple and thus two (or more variable are assigned as you loop.  2. I Thought that interitems() was returning the values, but I can now see that is not correct