# Sort a complex python dictionary?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm sorry if that question has already been asked before, I read some topics but it didn't help me so far.

I get this JSON response from a software API :

```
 {
    u 'code': 0, u 'message': u 'Found: 367', u 'objects': {
        u 'ApplicationSolution::15056': {
            u 'fields': {
                u 'id': u '15056',
                u 'name': u 'R'
            },
            u 'message': u '',
            u 'code': 0,
            u 'class': u 'ApplicationSolution',
            u 'key': u '15056'
        },
        u 'ApplicationSolution::15758': {
            u 'fields': {
                u 'id': u '15758',
                u 'name': u 'Z'
            },
            u 'message': u '',
            u 'code': 0,
            u 'class': u 'ApplicationSolution',
            u 'key': u '15758'
        },
        u 'ApplicationSolution::15053': {
            u 'fields': {
                u 'id': u '15053',
                u 'name': u 'E'
            },
            u 'message': u '',
            u 'code': 0,
            u 'class': u 'ApplicationSolution',
            u 'key': u '15053'
        },
        u 'ApplicationSolution::15050': {
            u 'fields': {
                u 'id': u '15050',
                u 'name': u 'C'
            },
            u 'message': u '',
            u 'code': 0,
            u 'class': u 'ApplicationSolution',
            u 'key': u '15050'
        },
}
```

I would like to sort this response with ApplicationSolution name (objects > ApplicationSolution:xxxxx > fields > name). I try to do this with sorted but I didn't find the right syntax :(

Anyone could help me please ?

Thank you so much !

Comment: What have you tried ? How did it end ?

Comment: You cannot sort a dictionary, so you'll have to let us know how you expect the output to look like.

Comment: Could you please provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do I iterate over a dictionary in sorted order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364519/in-python-how-do-i-iterate-over-a-dictionary-in-sorted-order)

Comment: @thebjorn I need the same output, but sorted with ApplicationSolution name. I guess I have to convert this dictionary to a list, it's not a problem, but I'm stucked with the usage of sorted then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first convert the dictionary to a list of 2-tuples, and then sort the list with the appropriate field. It can be as simple as (assuming the global dict is called `j`):

```
sorted([(k,v) for k,v in j['objects'].items()], key=(lambda x: x[1]['fields']['name']))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I tried to do something like that but my syntax wasn't good. Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

If `d` is your dict, then

```
def fieldname((k, v)):
    return v['fields']['name']
d['objects'] = list(sorted(d['objects'].items(), key=fieldname))
```

would do it in-situ.